# Adding services in different consul clients running on same host

Tags: docker, consul

I've followed the section of in [Testing a Consul cluster on a single host](https://hub.docker.com/r/progrium/consul/) using consul. Three consul servers are successfully added and running in same host for testing purpose. Afterwards, I've also followed the tutorial and created a consul client `node4` to expose ports. Is it possible to add more services and bind to one of those consul clients ?

Comment: That's the old Consul image/instructions. There's been an official Consul image for a few months now https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/  But... do you know that the new Docker "swarm mode" released in June doesn't need Consul anymore?

Comment: @Alkaline we still need consul to achieve high availability, isn't it ? https://docs.docker.com/swarm/multi-manager-setup/

Comment: You don't need Consul with the new "swarm mode". Service discovery and key/value store is now part of the docker daemon when it runs in a managed mode (swarm mode). It's much easier to setup. Unfortunately, it's also easy to follow the old legacy Swarm doc. Make sure you search for "swarm mode" when you google and make sure you look at the "swarm mode" pages in the Docker site. https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/  Typically, it's under the 'engine' path as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new 'swarm mode' instead of the legacy Swarm. Swarm mode doesn't require Consul. Service discovery and key/value store is now part of the docker daemon. Here's how to create a 3 nodes High Available cluster (3 masters).

1. Create three nodes

   ```
   docker-machine create --driver vmwarefusion node01
   docker-machine create --driver vmwarefusion node02
   docker-machine create --driver vmwarefusion node03
   ```
2. Find the ip of node01

   ```
   docker-machine ls
   ```
3. Set one as the initial swarm master

   ```
   docker $(docker-machine config node01) swarm init --advertise-addr <ip-of-node01>
   ```
4. Retrieve the token to let other nodes join as master

   ```
   docker $(docker-machine config node01) swarm join-token manager
   ```

   This will print out something like

   ```
   docker swarm join \
   --token SWMTKN-1-0siwp7rzqeslnhuf42d16zcwodk543l99liy0wuq1mern8s8u9-8mbsrxzu9mgfw7x6ehpxh0dof \
   192.168.40.144:2377
   ```
5. Add the other two nodes to the swarm **as masters**

   ```
   docker $(docker-machine config node02) swarm join \
   --token SWMTKN-1-0siwp7rzqeslnhuf42d16zcwodk543l99liy0wuq1mern8s8u9-8mbsrxzu9mgfw7x6ehpxh0dof \
   192.168.40.144:2377

   docker $(docker-machine config node03) swarm join \
   --token SWMTKN-1-0siwp7rzqeslnhuf42d16zcwodk543l99liy0wuq1mern8s8u9-8mbsrxzu9mgfw7x6ehpxh0dof \
   192.168.40.144:2377
   ```
6. Examine the swarm

   ```
   docker node ls
   ```

You should now be able to shutdown the leader node and see another pick up as manager.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for Consul, is to run consul one per HOST, and when you want to talk to consul, you always talk locally.  In general, everything 1 consul node knows, every other consul node also knows.  So you can just talk to your localhost consul (127.0.0.1:8500) and do everything you need to do.  When you add services, you add them to the local consul node that has the service's process on it. There are projects like Registrator (https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) That will automatically add services from running docker containers, which makes life easier.

Overall, welcome to Consul, it's great stuff!